# How to find Emitter and Collector of an LDR

Tags: sensor, resistors, light, ldr

How can we find the emitter and collector of an LDR. I am using it in the following circuit but I don't know how to identify which terminal of the LDR is emitter or collector.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo1id.jpg]

Here it is mentioned as Photo-transistor but it is basically 2 leg transistor which is hard to find in the market so I decided to use LDR.

Comment: Digikey offers 699 phototransistors. The majority of the first page is 2 terminal devices. What do *YOU* mean when you say "hard to find in the market"?

Comment: @W5VO Maybe he means his local market? The fact something is available on Digikey doesn't mean that it's accessible enough to use.

Comment: @AndrejaKo so does that mean it's too localized?

Comment: @W5VO I doubt it. Also the question isn't about phototransistors. It's about LDRs.

Comment: Hang on a minute, I'm totally puzzled now - in your [previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34313/light-sensor-using-photo-transistor) you give the part number as [ST1KL3B](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/kondenshi/ST1KL3B.pdf) which is definitely a phototransistor and what the answers were based upon. Now it's an LDR? If so what part number is it? LDRs are different to Phototransistors.

Comment: @Oli Glaser Maybe he wants a two-pin phototransistor? The linked one has 3 pins.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Any phototransistor should suffice, as you can just leave the base floating on a 3-pin phototransistor and it will function the same as a 2-pin.

Comment: @Oli Glaser I'm aware of that, but looking at the last sentence of the post, looks like OP isn't.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - sorry I see what you're getting at. The OP should hopefully be aware of this as it was mentioned to just leave the base floating in the previous question. I constructed the circuit above and took a couple of pictures to try and make things as clear as possible but he is still having trouble with his circuit, and this further post leaves me wondering whether he is actually using the part number mentioned, or a phototransistor at all. Hopefully things will become clear eventually ;-)

Comment: What is the gain that you are getting out of  your LDR? (I'm curious why you are using two gain stages. )

Comment: A LDR is **not** a phototransistor! Which one do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. Light dependent resistor is a resistor which means that it doesn't have a collector and emitter. It instead has two terminals that are used just like on regular resistor.

You can actually see that from the schematic symbol:

[image: LDR symbol from Wikipedia]

Both leads are the same and it doesn't matter in which direction current goes through it.

Comment: I think the OP was overthinking his phototransistor. This looks like a transistor that is not polarized, i.e., it doesnt mattter what end is connected to what, this will still act like a transistor. (Interesting fact, transistor = trans + resistor = changeable resistor)